# Why does 'flair' takes so much time to load?

Tags: discussion, flair

I have a little [blog](http://aljilogy.blogspot.fr) and I wanted to check the performance of the website using **[GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/aljilogy.blogspot.fr/1ajRlfoT)**.

In the *Timeline* of the downloaded elements by the browser, I found a surprise: The `.png` of my *Stack Overflow flair* takes too much time to load. This is definitely not normal. Please fix it.

[image: Timeline]

Comment: I've updated your GTmetrix link to point to results from an analysis of your first link. The results show a total time of 342 ms for the flair image.

Comment: that's because it is a second loaded , and the image stays on the browser

Comment: No, the server at `http://gtmetrix.com` does not cache results from previous tests of a page. That said, repeated tests do fluctuate quite a bit, between 1.4s and 73ms.

Comment: really strange !

Comment: wait let me test from **INDIA** not **Canada**.

Comment: check now please !

Comment: It only actually takes the server 287+61 ms to respond to your request (that's the purple and gray areas). The majority of the holdup (520ms) is being caused by "blocking", which is typical of non-asynchronous requests. I'm not sure why this is occurring with an image, but it is definitely a client side problem.

Comment: I will take this comment as an answer ... please copy it :)